# Hidden meaning in this song?

Tags: riddle

I was listening to a new song my wife recommended, and it had really strange lyrics.  I couldn't help thinking that there must be a hidden meaning here.  Then again, I'm getting old - maybe this is just what the kids are into nowadays?

> You can call me money
>   Grind me up until I'm sour
>   Say my name with a smile
>   And I'll just listen to my radio
>   And loaf around the house

Do you think there's another meaning here?

Hint #1

> I knew there was something strange going on because instead of happy or sad this song made me hungry!

Comment: Just a tip, you don't *need* to add a hint if the puzzle is easy enough without it. More often people add hints if a puzzle goes unsolved for a few hours or days.

Comment: Good call @Randal'Thor - I'll hold off on a hint next time

Comment: Does this require any knowledge of songs or artists?

Comment: @PilsNot3 Nope, I cant even remember who the artist is!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on all the other answers, I believe this song is describing

> a **cheeseburger.** (From OP, the intended answer was a **ham and cheese sandwich**, but a cheeseburger also works.) Each line is a description of an ingredient in a cheeseburger, from top to bottom.

You can call me money

> This is bread, as Rand al'Thor and Thomas Markov found.

Grind me up until I'm sour

> Mustard is a sour condiment that is made from grinding up mustard seeds and mixing it with water or vinegar.

Say my name with a smile

> This is cheese, as Prim3numbah found.

And I'll just listen to my radio

> "Ham" is a term for amateur radio. (Hamburger is a term that can mean ground meat, which a cheeseburger must have.)

And loaf around the house

> This is also bread, as the aforementioned solvers found.

Comment: (rot13)  Lbh tbg rirel pyhr evtug, ohg pnzr hc jvgu n qvssrerag svany nafjre guna V unq.  Jung ryfr zvtug unir gubfr vaterqvragf va gung beqre?  Unz zvtug abg vzcyl ohetre...

Comment: @Nico Hmm, are you looking for simply rot13(n trarevp fnaqjvpu) then? I don't really have specialized knowledge on that topic, so if it's a specific kind you're talking about, I may need a few more hints

Comment: @Pilsnot3 - Great solve!  rot13(Lrf, whfg n unz naq purrfr fnaqjvpu unun.  V'yy npprcg lbhe nafjre, fvapr lbh pyrneyl tbg vg evtug - abg fher vs lbh pna hcqngr jvgu gung fcrpvsvp vasb be abg.)

Comment: Great reasoning, but you say rot13("Purrfrohetre nyfb jbexf." V'ir arire urneq bs n purrfr ohetre jvgu unz _naq_ jvgubhg nal fbeg bs tebhaq zrng (hfhnyyl orrs)) :)

Comment: @Johnson Oh, I was thinking about rot13(unzohetre, juvpu V guvax pna nyfb zrna tebhaq zrng.) I'll add that in to clarify

Comment: Ah right - thanks for clarification. I think a case of US vs UK English confusion on my part - to me rot13(unzohetre zrnaf gur jubyr ohetre (fnaqjvpu?) ohg V guvax va gur HF vg pna zrna whfg gur zrng cnggl?)

Comment: @Johnson Yup, rot13(va gur HF, vg'f bsgra pbzzba gb fnl "unzohetre zrng" jura ersreevat gb tebhaq orrs, fvapr gung'f cerggl zhpu gur bayl ernfba jr hfr tebhaq orrs.) :)

Comment: I didn't consider that we have a global audience - I'll try and keep that in mind when creating future riddles.  Regardless, great job putting the pieces together @PilsNot3

Comment: OK, that's pretty clever :-) I assumed everything was just describing one thing, and couldn't see how your word makes sense, but that's very neat! (cc @Nico)

Answer (score 6):

The answer is

> dough.

*You can call me money*

> Dough is a slang word for money.

*Grind me up to till I'm sour*

> Sourdough.

*Say my name with a smile*

> Doh?

*And I'll just listen to my radio*

> Maybe another slang word? Not sure.

*And loaf around the house*

> A loaf is made out of dough.

Comment: (rot13)  Qbhtu vf n fynat jbeq sbe zbarl - ohg ner gurer bgure fvzvyne jbeqf?  Lbh'er qrsvavgryl ba gur evtug cngu.  Vg srryf yvxr lbhe zvqqyr nafjref trg jrnxre naq jrnxre.  Pbhyq vg or lbhe nafjre bayl jbexf sbe cneg bs gur evqqyr?

Answer (score 4):

I believe the hidden message you're looking for is:

> Cheese

Comment: (rot13)  V guvax lbh pbhyq or ba gur evtug genpx, ohg zbfg bs gur fbat unf abguvat gb qb jvgu purrfr.  Jung ryfr pbhyq or tbvat ba urer?

Answer (score 4):

Similar to Rand's answer:

> Bread

You can call me money

> Money is sometimes called bread (see clue for the radio).

Grind me up till I'm sour

> Sourdough

Say my name with a smile

> I dare you to say pumpernickel without laughing.

And I'll just listen to my radio

> Billy Joel's Piano man "And they sit at the bar and put bread in my jar"

And loaf around the house

> A loaf of bread.

Comment: (rot13) Lbh'er nofbyhgryl ba gur evtug genpx urer, ohg abg dhvgr gurer.  V ybir gung lbh jrer noyr gb pbzr hc jvgu ernfbaf sbe gur zvqqyr yvarf gb svg nafjre - ohg qvq lbh abgvpr gung gurl orpnzr zber naq zber bs n fgergpu?

Comment: @Nico rot13(sbe shgher ersrerapr, guvf sbeznggvat sbe ebg13 jbexf orfg orpnhfr fbzr hfref unir n oebjfre rkgrafvba gung nhgbzngvpnyyl pbairegf vg ba ubire)

Comment: I also thought of this possible word, but in the end I thought the "sour" clue fit better with my word than yours.